# azure stream analytics implementation or the best approach

Tags: azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

I am new to Steam analytics and I need help here to achieve a specific task.
I have telemetry data coming from iot hub in this format.
Basically i will be getting machines telemetry data and the stage of the operations on that machine streamed to iot hub.
The stages will be indicated with tag ex:"stageid":"stage1". I need to calculate the time taken for each stage using stream analytics based on timestamp and stage tag.

packet Ex:

```
[{
"Payload": {
    "devid": "01",
    "locid": "loc01",
    "machid": "mac01",
    "stageid": "stage1",
    "timestamp": "2020-01-24T09:22:00.3270000Z"
},
"Payload": {
    "devid": "02",
    "locid": "loc01",
    "machid": "mac01",
    "stageid": "stage1",
    "timestamp": "2020-01-24T09:22:00.3270000Z"
}
```

}]

```
[{
"Payload": {
    "devid": "01",
    "locid": "loc01",
    "machid": "mac01",
    "stageid": "stage2",
    "timestamp": "2020-01-24T09:26:00.3270000Z"
},
"Payload": {
    "devid": "02",
    "locid": "loc01",
    "machid": "mac01",
    "stageid": "stage2",
    "timestamp": "2020-01-26T09:24:00.3270000Z"
}
```

}]

pls help me can we achieve this with query and what could be the query or what is the other best approach?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my knowledge,your needs can't be implemented by ASA built-in features. ASA is a real-time collect data and analytics service.In other words,data need to be processed in the real-time.Current data can't wait for next dataset to do some calculate or merge things. Even if you could use [windows function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-window-functions) and group by,i believe the frequency of messages pushed by the device is also variable.

As a workaround,my idea is using [iot-hub azure function trigger](https://azure.microsoft.com/ja-jp/blog/how-to-use-azure-functions-with-iot-hub-message-routing/).Inside trigger,you could use code to parse message and save key columns(stageid,timestamp,devid) into some storage,maybe azure table storage. Before every insert,just grab latest row of current device to calculate the time taken with current message so that you could produce that time to store in other residence.In the end, update the latest row for every device.

Comment: Thanks Jay for the response. I have 1 more use case where i have to detect change in siteid in the job. looks this also not possible in ASA directly or pls let me know if it is and sample